# How to derive and interpret the duration of a call option?

Tags: options, fixed-income, delta, duration, call

I [read here](https://www.analystforum.com/forums/cfa-forums/cfa-level-iii-forum/91254359) that CFA students are taught that

$$ D_{C} = \frac{\Delta_{C} D_{B} B}{C} $$

Where $D$ is the duration, $\Delta_{C}$ is the first derivative of the options price with regards to the price of the underlying, $C$ is the price of a European call option on an underlying fixed income instrument, such as Bunds, and $B$ is the spot price of the underlying.

I have not been able to find a reference to this in *Hull (2018) OFOD*, or online, other than a reference to the  Schweser CFA books "*30f - fixed income portfolio management II*", which I do not have access to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an approximation (to first order) based on the idea that the option gives you access to the underlying, but with leverage.

Let the duration of the underlying be $D_B$.

The expression $\lambda=\Delta_c\frac{B}{C}$ is called the elasticity of the option [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Lambda), defined as "the percentage change in option value per percentage change in the underlying price".

Consequently the option reacts to changes in interest rates more/less than the underlying does, using $\lambda$ as a scale factor.

So $D_c= \lambda D_B = \Delta_c\frac{B}{C} D_B$